# bitsets in C++ using VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, bitset

I can't figure out if I'm doing anything wrong here, hopefully someone here can enlighten me.

I have a class `Flags`, this is an extremely simplified version but I declare a bitset

```
class Flags
{
private:
    //List of 8 bits
    std::bitset<8> _P;
public:
    Flags();
}
```

On my constructor I initialise it as

```
Flags::Flags()
    : _P(32ul)
{}
```

But it won't compile and gives me the error

> error C2668: 'std::bitset<_Bits>::bitset' : ambiguous call to
>   overloaded function

This is compiled in VS2010 SP1 64 bit but as a 32bit program

EDIT

Accepted answer is for the above but as a side note could anyone explain why when using the default constructor (which should initialise them all to zero's) they aren't all set to zero's?

```
_p.to_ulong()
```

returns 1390560944
and _p looks like

```
[8](0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1)
```

Comment: Paste the entire error, and that identifiers that begin with underscore followed by upper-case letter are reserved for implementation — change the member's name.

Comment: There is no section below it that lists the various ambiguous cases?

Comment: Ah... I was looking at the error list not the output! Apologies my bad. Mark's answer has "solved" it anyway

Comment: Just saw your edit - that looks worthy of a new question!

Comment: In that case I shall do just that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in VC according to http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532897/problems-constructing-a-bitset-from-an-unsigned-long-in-the-vc-rc

Also note that identifiers starting with `_` and a capital letter are reserved for the implementation and illegal to use in your program.

EDIT: According to the workaround page (if I read it right), the workaround is to cast your value to `unsigned long long` instead of `unsigned long`.

Comment: thanks @Mark B, have a look at the edit though see what you think of that