# bitsets in C++ using VS2010 (another)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, bitset

I just asked another question about bitsets which turns out to be a bug in VS2010
[bitsets in C++ using VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947322/bitsets-in-c-using-vs2010/)

However upon changing the constructor I used for the bitset I've run into another problem (as described in the edit of the other question)

When using the default constructor for a bitset, it isn't being initialised to 0's but instead it's being set to

```
[8](0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1)
```

And `_p.to_ulong()` returns `1390560944`

Here's the code

```
class Flags
{
private:
    //List of 8 bits
    std::bitset<8> _p;
public:
    Flags();
}

Flags::Flags()
    : _p()
{}
```

I also just tried using `: _p(32)` but that caused the same bits to be set as above, however the value returned from `to_ulong()` is `1437615792`

What's going on?

Edit: This is compiled in VS2010 SP1 64 bit, as a 32bit program

Edit 2:

In the comments below, I said I could replicate it in a simple program - I was able to twice but since then it's been fine every time - maybe I was just being slow, been a long day.

In my other project (which is an emulator I'm attempting) I have narrowed it down to some arrays of function pointers. If I take out where they are assigned values then I don't get any dodgey behaviour, those arrays can be seen here

http://pastebin.com/QyiJGzNd

That code won't compile because the memory addressing functions won't be present and to include those I would have to include a bunch of other classes etc etc. But why would assigning values to function pointer arrays affect the values of a bitset? The bitset will be initialised before `init()` gets called

Comment: Can't you use boost bitset until the VS2010 implementation is fixed?

Comment: So is this yet another bug? Because it's completely different to what my other question is about

Comment: I can't repro this behavior at all with VS2010 SP1. Are you using RTM or SP1?

Comment: @tom502 : Well, again, I can't repro this. Can you post a more complete code sample that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Hm, I was unable to reproduce it. Can you post the exact code (including creating the instance) that causes the behavior?

Comment: @dark_charlie not easily really, but I can reproduce it in an empty project with just the code above and `Flags f = Flags();` in main

Comment: Can't reproduce that over here.

Comment: @tom502 : I'd venture to say it's just you. ;-] I.e., something is wrong with your computer/installation.

Comment: @ildjarn :S don't say that! Also, just noticed, the value that is returned is different every time I run it

Comment: @tom502 : Sounds like a classic case of memory corruption. I doubt anyone can help at this point without being able to go through your actual code with a debugger.

Comment: @ildjarn stepped all the way through that init function, it's when it stepped out that the bitset got corrupted. Great.

Comment: @tom502 : It might help if you also post the code constructing and initializing the instance of `MPU` and using `MPU::P`.

Comment: @ildjarn see my answer *hangs head*

Comment: @tom502 : Glad you figured it out fairly quickly. :-] It's that much worse when you waste a full day or two on things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it

I have this array (note the index)

```
void (MPU::*_STY[0x94])(BIT_8 ** pSource, const BIT_8 args[]); // STY
```

This is in my assignment list (note the index)

```
_STY[0x94] = &MPU::ZeroPageX_SourceOnly;
```

I think I just learnt my lesson

Comment: Out of bounds array indexing, the oldest bug in the book.